# difference between WORKER_EVICTOR and WORKER_BLOCK_ANNOTATOR

Tags: alluxio

can you explain what's the difference between WORKER_EVICTOR and WORKER_BLOCK_ANNOTATOR，and why alluxio abandoned WORKER_EVICTOR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We moved from passive background eviction to active in-line eviction in order to prevent many problems happening around peak capacity. For more through explanation, see this video's section starting from 14:50 -- https://www.alluxio.io/resources/videos/alluxio-architecture-and-scaling-performance/